# How to keep track of GPU memory on google colab and free it in a proper way?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a deep neural network (DNN) on `Google Colab` with the use of the `PyTorch` framework.

So far, I am debugging my network, and in order to do this, I reinitialize it each time.
But after doing so several times I am running out of GPU memory. The first thing to think about is to free the memory occupied by the network.
The solution, suggested here https://forums.fast.ai/t/clearing-gpu-memory-pytorch/14637 :

```
del model
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Doesn't work. There is definetely option of restarting a session, but doing it each time is rather annoying, because it takes some time to load the data and process it in order to run a network.

Is there some way to clear the GPU memory surely on `Google Colab`, and keep track of its usage?

In the case I am running out of memory I would like to figure the reason - the exact place, where memory allocation has failed and have a look at the objects, occupying it

Comment: Your question is titled as "How to keep *track* of GPU memory..." while the body tells that you want to clear the GPU cache. So, what is exactly are you looking for? :)

Comment: @AndrewNaguib Ok, maybe the title is a bit misleading, I want to free the GPU memory and understand which objects occupy it